# Kinda like dynamic function in java/android

Tags: java, android

I am coming from PHP to Java and I have some questions about "dynamic" functions.

Kinda like in php where you can do an `include(VARNAME.".php");` and if varname is `a` it'll include `a.php` if its `x` it'll include `x.php`.

I wanna do that in Java but with functions.
Kinda like I have a varname and I want to include a function. So if varname is `Test` it'll include `test()` but I have a bunch of functions and its a nuisance to do

```
if(varname == "x"){ x(); }.
```

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `if(varname == "x")` is surely not what you want.  This is a common Java mistake and will check the object identity, not the object value.  You want `if(varname.equals("x"))`.

Second, this isn't very idiomatic Java.  As Jason pointed out, you can use reflection to do a dynamic method look-up.  However, there is almost certainly a better design for what you are trying to accomplish.

Java is a very different language from PHP.  Trying to apply PHP idioms to Java will only cause you pain and suffering.

Having said all that, I think this is roughly the code you are looking for:

```
Method method = this.class.getDeclaredMethod("x", new Class[] {});
method.invoke(this, new Object[] {});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your varname equates to a function on the class you are in, you could theoretically use reflection to accomplish this.  See [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) from Sun/Oracle for more details